# Android Alarmmanager repeats unwanted

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to set AlarmManager to repeat on every 24 hours but my code does not work.

I set AlarmManager in MainActivity to trigger a pop-up notification using AlarmReceiver which sends an Intent to MainActivity.

I also check AlarmManger whether it is set but it returns always false when I do not use alarmIntent2 which is uncommented by (###) in my code.
And if I use alarmIntent2 then I get no notification, AlarmManager is then not correctly set.

Every time when MainActivity is called, AlarmManager is again set.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks.

MainActivity.class

```
MainActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent myIntent  = this.getIntent();
    if(myIntent.getExtras() != null) {
        String nid = myIntent.getExtras().containsKey("nid") ? myIntent.getExtras().getString("nid") : "-";
        if(nid.equals("1234")) {
            startFragmentActivityToShowMessage();
        }
        else {

            addNotification();
        }

    }
}


private void addNotification() {
        boolean alarmUp = false;
        alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent("com.mypackage.AlarmReceiver.class"),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if(!alarmUp) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 01);

            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, com.mypackage.AlarmReceiver.class);
            // (###) Intent alarmIntent2 = new Intent("com.mypackage.AlarmReceiver.class"); (###)
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60* 24, pendingIntent);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke. I resolved.

Intents in

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent,..)
```

must be created on same way. Then I can check If AlarmManager is already set or not. That resolved problem.

Example:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
```

or

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("com.mypackage.AlarmReceiver.class");
```

By this way checks in below works fine.

```
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
boolean alarmUp = false;
    alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            alarmIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

and

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60* 24, pendingIntent);
```

Second way with fullyqualified package name I have not tested yet but It should work I think.